# Scroll to next <div> when pressing 'j'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think you all have seen this feature on facebook. When you press `j`, the scroll position jumps to the next story and when you press `k` it scrolls to the previous story.

Now, if I have a lot of divs  with the class `.story` (In the snippet they all have the same height; but, actually, they'll be different), how can I navigate through them (scroll to the next and previous `.story`) by pressing `j` and `k` like on facebook?

```css
body{  
  background-color:#ecf0f1;
}

.story
{
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know javascript?

Comment: I think the solution is some jQuery, I just am not sure what would be the most, emm, right way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  var forward;
  if (e.keyCode == 106) {
    forward = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 107) {
    forward = false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  
  if (!$(".story.current").length) {
    $(".story:first").addClass("current");
  }
  
  if ($(".story.current").length) {
    var current = $(".story.current");
    var next;
    if (forward) {
      next = current.next(".story")
    } else {
      next = current.prev(".story");
    }
    if (next.length) {
      current.removeClass("current");
      next.addClass("current");
    } else {
      alert("nope.");
    }
  }
  
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".current").offset().top }, 100);
});
```

```css
body{  
  background-color:#ecf0f1;
}

.story
{
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="story">
  a
</div>
<div class="story">
  b
</div>
<div class="story">
  c
</div>
<div class="story">
  d
</div>
<div class="story">
  e
</div>
<div class="story">
  f
</div>
<div class="story">
  g
</div>
<div class="story">
  h
</div>
<div class="story">
  i
</div>
<div class="story">
  j
</div>
```

Comment: I'll mark this one as the right answer; but first, do you know how to make it so when it reaches the end it doesn't start again but return someting or maybe an alert or whatever?

Comment: just add the "current" class to the first item on the list right away, so it knows where to start. delete the second if, because it'll be useless. then, before removing the class from the current item, check if the next item exist. if it does, give it the class. if it doesn't, show the alert.

Comment: there, i fixed it for you

Answer (score 1):

I will just add one more solution which seems to me a little simpler:

```
var $story = $('.story');

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var index;

    if (e.keyCode == 74) {
        index = $story.filter('.focused').index() + 1;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 75) {
        index = $story.filter('.focused').index() - 1;
    }

    if (index < $story.length && index >= 0) {
        $story.removeClass('focused').eq(index).addClass('focused');   
    }

    $("html, body").animate({ 
        scrollTop: $focused.offset().top 
    }, 200);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vfw15v7d/